# Custom Search Page For a Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, modern-experience, administration

Is there a way to create and assign a custom search results page for a Document Library?

I've created one at the site level, but if you navigate into a document library and do a search the results are bound to the view that is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

You cannot create a custom search results page specifically for a document library in SharePoint online modern experience.

Currently, you can only create a custom search results page for SharePoint site as mentioned in below links:

1. [Create a custom search results page in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/create-search-results-pages)
2. [Creating custom search results pages in SharePoint Online](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-search-blog/creating-custom-search-results-pages-in-sharepoint-online/ba-p/1141515)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a page and add the library webpart to the page.  Then when a user does a search from the top of the page, it will use the custom search page for the results page.
[image]

Comment: The search results will not be specific to this document library only. It will show the search results from other libraries on the site as well.

Comment: You are correct, but my custom search results page only pulls from my document library, which, in this case, is how the client wants the search results to perform.

Comment: ok, but next time you want the search results from another list/library on same site, the custom search results page will not return those results.

Comment: Correct.  I would need to update the search scope to include the list/library.  @Ganesh do you know how to customize the PNP search results webpart?  take a look at my other question at the bottom of this thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306853/customizing-pnp-search-results/309179#309179